Application-oriented YouTube / Course recommendations?
I'm looking for a resource to self teach MILP modeling techniques. I have no interest in starting a career as a research scientist at Gurobi so how these models work (Simplex, Interior Point, etc.) is not of interest to me.
Rather, I'd like to understand broad classes of problems and common modeling techniques (ex: column generation) that are solver-agnostic. (Context: improving logistic decisions at a tech company.). Are any such recommendations available?

There are many resources, you can find at OR.SE. (e.g. this one). Also please, be aware that without having a good knowledge of e.g. the Simplex algorithm, it would be hard to understand how a method like column generation works in practice.

Related: Recommendations for OR video channels (YouTube etc.)

@A.Omidi perhaps not the best example I could have offered. I have actually implemented simplex before, see https://github.com/jdmoore7/simplex_algorithm/blob/master/simplex.py. But the experience wasn’t that enlightening. The business problem to math problem translation is where I see the biggest growth opportunity for myself.

For what it's worth, I cover modeling techniques from a business point of view (not solver API point of view, which isn't LP anyway) in the Timefold Academy videos. For example, how to model VRP time windows, task dependencies, overtime, etc.

Here are few resources which I typically recommend to folks who are working in data science (ML) and looking to do some OR modeling.

Hands-on modelling: https://www.gurobi.com/resources/intro-to-optimization-through-the-lens-of-data-science/
Deep dive on discrete optimization (including some theory which is easy to follow): https://www.coursera.org/learn/discrete-optimization#syllabus

While the request was for youtube links only, I would still like to share these two books since they focus more on practical aspects of modeling (and very comprehensive), and are easy read for someone with basic understanding of OR concepts.

Supply Chain Modeling. Covers all aspects of Supply
Chain including logistics.
https://www.amazon.com/Supply-Chain-Engineering-Applications-Operations-dp-1032254750/dp/1032254750
Amazing book which focuses more on applications and modeling (less on
theory, theory references are provided when needed)
https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Model+Building+in+Mathematical+Programming%2C+5th+Edition-p-9781118443330

I recently offered a set of lectures (along with few friends in OR community) where we have tried document ideas/practices to help OR practitioners in industry. Link for the slides here:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/hvk7njkhq6kz2wgiuebh3/AL824J-26VvpFXSoFj2LWCA?rlkey=enpowk33bmpdy1iulwvjw7hxx&st=zr47kgq7&dl=0

